# How can I insert the style into async container DOM using style-loader?

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader

As the title question, in my code, I create a  container `<div id="root"></div>` in `window.onload` event, but I have no idea about how to config the the webpack style-loader options?

The container

```js
window.onload = function () {
  // console.log(chrome.runtime.getManifest().id);
  container = document.createElement('div');
  container.setAttribute('id', 'app');
  document.body.appendChild(container);
  const shadow = container.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
};
```

The webpack config

```
...    
{
    loader: 'style-loader',
    options: {
      insert: function (linkTag) {
        // insert into doms
        // no circus
        setTimeout(() => {
          const parent =
            document.querySelector('#app').shadowRoot;
          parent.appendChild(linkTag);
        }, 3000);
      },
    },
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Use two shadow-DOMs to complete it, and this will be avoid async operations in style-loader option.

1. In style-loader `insert function` create a shadow-DOM  container to place the generated style
2. In actual React app shadow-DOM, move the style into it.

here is the DOM I generated

[image]

> Discussions: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/discussions/15075